# Release from back choke when your face and body turn to the floor

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, self-defense

Is there a way to release from back choke when your all body is on the floor and your face (and body) turn to the floor. Is there a difference if the choker is on your body or is beside you? Videos or pictures will be highly appreciated. There is no space between body and the choked hands so it is different from the regular known back choke.

Comment: What kind of effect should this kind of choke have, other than simply pinning you on the floor?

Comment: The choke stops your breath...

Comment: Actually the main pressure of the choke would be on my neck, so maybe I understand It wrongly, do you have a picture of what you exactly mean?

Comment: Thanks @mitro. I tried to find picture or video but unfortunately I haven't found. You are right the choke is on the neck but like any other choke the front hand goes in the gap between the neck to the floor and the other hand is holding the it at top with leverage on the neck.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this but on the floor: https://youtu.be/LppnEfRoFIM ?

Comment: Same choke but the whole body and the stomach are on the floor and the face looks at the floor.

Comment: Thanks @mattm, it is a totally different situation, you can't do the drills mentioned there since your body and face are on the floor. You can't use your hands since there is no gap.

Comment: Whether you are facing down is not an important detail. You can always roll so that you are facing up because your opponent is parallel to you and can't effectively stop a roll. But that change in position does not improve your escape situation. I don't know what gap you are talking about. How is there a gap in a normal naked rear choke situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're face-down flat on your belly getting rear naked choked, you done f---ed up a long time ago, and most likely you're not getting out. That's just how it goes.

The back-mounted rear naked choke is what's called a "terminal position", meaning there is no better place for the dominant person to go, and properly applied there is no escape.

Your best chance is to somehow simultaneously deal with both the arms around your neck and the control of your hips. You'll need to hip escape and remove any leg/foot hooks controlling your lower body and trunk while also removing, step by step, the arm that secures the choking arm and then the choking arm. You'll then need to move your torso laterally so it is not aligned with your opponent's. This is quite difficult and usually fails, because the person in a dominant position is by definition in a more secure situation.